# site preloader actually works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloader

The following script is the most common I found to be used for managing the preloader but does this actually work or is it just some stuff we display for few seconds and assume the content of the site would have been loaded by then?

**Here is that script.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.loader').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
  $('.preloader').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
  $('body').delay(1500).css({'overflow':'visible'});
  });
});
```

and then the HTML

```
<body>  
<div class="preloader">
<div class="loader"> .... </div>
</div>
<div class="content">...</div>
```

Another thing i would like to ask is if we can have a simple preloader that actually works with just JavaScript instead of jQuery.... there seems to be some problem displayed in console when using the latest version of jQuery

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `load` event fires when everything has loaded. But you're kind of destroying the point of dynamically loading resources, which is a thing the browser does automatically to allow access to content faster.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol so the script i found is just to fake the loading? i mean its just displays some stuff for few seconds assuming the site content would have loaded by then?

Comment: No, the page has some "loading screen", and when the `load` event fires then the code removes it. There's no assumption involved, the event means you *know* it has loaded. But there's no need to wait for everything to load before allowing the user to see your page.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol i added few broken links of files including image source just to check the loader but it didnt work. i thought it would keep displaying the loading because of that.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol is there a way to do that with just JavaScript instead of jQuery?

Comment: As you have discovered, failure of an img to load will not supreess the window's load event. When an img fails, an `error` event is dispatched but does not suppress `window.onload`.

Comment: try remove '$(window).on('load', function() {'